# R: retrieve dataframe name from another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe `dataselect` that tells me what dataframe to use for each case of an analysis (let's call this the relevant dataframe).

The case is assigned dynamically, and therefore which dataframe is relevant depends on that case.

Based on the case, I would like to assign the relevant dataframe to a pointer "relevantdf". I tried:

```
datasetselect <- data.frame(case=c("case1","case2"),dataset=c("df1","df2"))

df1 <- data.frame(var1=letters[1:3],var2=1:3)
df2 <- data.frame(var1=letters[4:10],var2=4:10)


currentcase <- "case1"
relevantdf <- get(datasetselect[datasetselect$case == currentcase,"dataset"]) # relevantdf should point to df1
```

I don't understand if I have a problem with the `get()` function or the subsetting process.

Comment: well, it works if you add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in your `datasetselect` definition. Or convert it to character by doing `get(as.character(datasetselect[datasetselect$case == currentcase,"dataset"]))`

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there, the problem is that the dataset column from datasetselect is a factor, you just need to convert it to character

You can add this line after the definition of datasetselect:

```
datasetselect$dataset <- as.character(datasetselect$dataset)
```

And you get your expected output

```
> relevantdf
  var1 var2
1    a    1
2    b    2
3    c    3
```